# Firebase cloud messaging: disable the popup notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an android app which has a separate activity for notifications. I integrated firebase cloud messaging to my app for sending notifications to users. When I send a notification from the console, by default a notification pops up from the app. I want disable that notification and save the message from notification to a database. Later when user opens the app it gets the notifications data from the database and show them to the user. That means I don't want to show popup notifications to user, I want to show them only if user opens the app. My question is: How can I disable the default notification which pops up when a message is received?

Comment: Notification message are recieved in the system tray  and I don't think you can do much about it , when you send the message through fcm console try to attach optional data payload , which you will recieve in `onmessagerecieved()`  and then you can add those data in the database , see more here for explanation (see the table) https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I can attach data payload and receive them. But the notification will still pops up when message is received because I must add notification text from the console. I don't want to show notification to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a message without a notification, you should not use the Firebase console to send that message.  Instead, you will need to write some code on your desktop or backend, usually with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), to [send a message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) with a data payload.  The app will silently receive that message, and you can decide what to do with it from the callback you receive.  Start with the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) to set up the client app.  Be sure you are sending messages with **only** a data payload.  It must not contain a notification payload.